# Validity of Vietnam draft avoidance through having a father change son's draft status

Tags: legal-history, vietnam, draft, selection

In 1969 a graduate student in receipt of a 1-D draft deferment status pending enrolment in law school and undertaking an ROTC commitment  hears of upcoming change of military selection process to one decided by lottery.

Noting that in a fair lottery he has an 80% chance of avoiding the first 73 selections of candidate birthdays and that such a number of draftees would likely satisfy the military's quota for his age group, he asks his father to go to the state draft board and request his status to be changed to 1-A, i.e. fit and available for the draft.

Suppose his gamble backfires and his birthday is drawn in the early selections from the lottery. Can a shameless graduate student make a case for restoration of his previous 1-D status based on an assertion that his father misunderstood his intentions during their conversation preceding his father's request to the draft board, and thus acted without his consent in obtaining a change to 1-A status ?

Please note that this is a purely legal question. It therefore does not suggest that such a course of action would be in the personal interest of a graduate student with public service career aspirations.

Comment: What was the point of describing a situation, then asking a question about a modified situation? I suggest describing the situation you're asking about, and removing all the irrelevant details about Nixon and suchlike.

Comment: Was the student considered a minor when the father reclassified the draft status of his son? For this question I think the extensive background information is appropriate..

Comment: I have just amended the original post to (I hope) Sneftel's satisfaction. @Mark Johnson: No - the student was ~ 22 at that time. He happened to be a graduate student overseas but nonetheless was in a country with good telephone/telegram links to US and in possession of adequate monies for notepaper, pens and stamping.

Answer (score 1):

### Since this is a hypothetical legal question: no

Committing fraud and perjury is not a legal excuse from the draft.

Comment: But it is *possible* that a student in such circumstances *is* telling the truth, i.e. a concerned father could act thus to "save" his son. So it is not obvious perjury. I don't see where the fraud comes in. If the father brought no letter signed by his son then how can the draft board take such a significant decision with the son's life?

Comment: @Trunk, then it's fraud and perjury by the father.

Comment: Obviously I am no lawyer. Yet it would be unjust for the son to suffer the hardships brought about by wrong representations made by his father on his behalf. Wasn't the draft board remiss in not seeking a signed letter from the son, albeit presented by his father?

Comment: @Trunk what punishment is the son suffering?

Comment: What punishment is the son suffering? Bearing in mind that being conscripted is not a punishment.

Comment: The son's life is at much more risk in Vietnam than in the ROTC program. That he be so as a result of his father's presumptive action without his own consent is in effect an unmerited punishment.

Comment: @trunk compulsory military service is not a legal punishment; it applied to people who commit no crime. Of course, if the father’s crimes are proved: that the transfer to 1-A was a fraud, then the transfer never happened and the son always had a 1-D classification.

Comment: So if I had 4 sons in USA 1969 and I went to the local draft board I could effectively send the lot of them to their  likely deaths in Vietnam without their express consent ?

Comment: There is a branch of law called administrative law here in Ireland, perhaps your state has an equivalent. This provides safeguards against decisions of public bodies upon individuals and other entities. Judicial review of such decisions is permitted. Decisions of public bodies must not offend against reason and common sense. Signing away the health or even life of an adult person on no greater an authorization than the word of a parent surely falls into this category.